# Protractor / Selenium standalone error "403 Forbidden for Proxy"

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor

I'm using Protractor to run end-to-end JS tests within my Rails app. The following spec is failing:

```
# my_ctrl_spec.js.coffee
describe 'MyCtrl', ->
  it 'does a thing', ->
    expect( browser ).toBeTruthy()
    browser.get '/'
```

The spec passes with the last line commented out, but actually trying to navigate WebDriver gives me "Error 403 Forbidden for Proxy" on the rendered page.

Here is my protractor_conf.js file:

```
require('coffee-script/register');

exports.config = {
  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome',
  },

  specs: ['spec/javascripts/e2e/**/*_spec.js.coffee'],

  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  seleniumServerJar: './node_modules/protractor/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-2.44.0.jar',
  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:4444',

  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000
  }
};
```

I'm also getting some errors telling me that "retries looking for angular exceeded," but I think that's *because* of the 403 error, not vice-versa.

Some system deets:

- Mac OS X 10.9.5
- Selenium 2.44.0
- Protractor 1.4.0

Can anyone see anything wrong with my setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you used `baseUrl` the wrong way: it should be the URL of the page you want to test, not the selenium adress.

If you use a webserver it could be `http://localhost:8000` for example, if the page is already online just put its URL ;)

```js
// A base URL for your application under test. Calls to protractor.get()
// with relative paths will be prepended with this.
baseUrl: 'http://localhost:9876',
```

Take a look at [protractor/referenceConf.js](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/55a91ea137395891248db148df75dd6408c3b3a2/docs/referenceConf.js#L148) for more info.